# Is it possible to use std::chrono::duration with Rep type as double? I get compiler error in vs2012 when I try

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, type-conversion, c++-chrono

I get a following compiler (vs2012) error:

> Error 3 error C2679: binary '+=' : no operator found which takes a
>   right-hand operand of type 'const std::chrono::duration<_Rep,_Period>'
>   (or there is no acceptable conversion) c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\chrono 749

My definition of duration is:

```
// Tick interval type in nanoseconds
typedef std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1, 100000000>> tick_interval_type;
```

Same error when I use float... It only compiles when the Rep type of duration is integer.

Can someone please help?

Edit (more complete log from Output):

> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   11.0\vc\include\chrono(749): error C2679: binary '+=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const
>   std::chrono::duration<_Rep,_Period>' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion) with [
>       _Rep=double,
>       _Period=std::nano ] c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\chrono(166): could be 'std::chrono::duration<_Rep,_Period>
>   &std::chrono::duration<_Rep,_Period>::operator +=(const
>   std::chrono::duration<_Rep,_Period> &)' with [
>       _Rep=__int64,
>       _Period=std::nano ] while trying to match the argument list '(std::chrono::nanoseconds, const
>   std::chrono::duration<_Rep,_Period>)' with [
>       _Rep=double,
>       _Period=std::nano ] c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\thread(164) : see reference to function template instantiation 'xtime std::_To_xtime(const
>   std::chrono::duration<_Rep,_Period> &)' being compiled with [
>       _Rep=double,
>       _Period=std::nano ] c:\dev\projects\revolverx\classes\ticker.h(78) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void
>   std::this_thread::sleep_for(const
>   std::chrono::duration<_Rep,_Period> &)' being compiled with [
>       _Rep=double,
>       _Period=std::nano ]

Comment: Are there any more messages in the build log? For example that tells what types was used and what was expected? Please edit your question to include the *complete* error log.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg, my fault, question updated. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<chrono>` in Visual Studio is broken. It doesn't work with mixed type arithmetic, which, arguably, is [one of the main features](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=16719932#16719932) of `<chrono>`. You get this error because one of the sides uses `__int64` nanos and the other uses `double` nanos.

I recommend either dropping it in favor of a real C++ implementation, or using Boost.Chrono.

Comment: R. Martinho Fernandes, nice to hear it! So what to do in my case, to use `typedef std::chrono::duration<std::chrono::nanoseconds> tick_interval_type;` instead? By the way, will it work in XCode?

Comment: What I did when I ran into this problem was just switching to Boost.Chrono, like this: https://github.com/rmartinho/nonius/blob/devel/include/nonius/clock.h%2B%2B#L25. Alternatively, you can add `duration_cast`s everywhere, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Update:  I've come upon this question four years after it was originally posted, and I've tested this on Visual Studio 2015.  It does compile now.  For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    typedef std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1, 100000000>> tick_interval_type;  // Originally posted line
    tick_interval_type tick {0};
    tick += std::chrono::microseconds(3);
    std::cout << std::setprecision(6) << std::fixed << tick.count();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
300.000000
```

Comment: @JHBonarius, Alright, 3 years, 11 months.  We'll round that to four.  :)  Updated.