# Compile errors when including std::mutex before jemalloc.h

Tags: c++, c++11, include, std

This

```
//CSocket.h
#ifndef __SERVER_CSOCKET_H__
#define __SERVER_CSOCKET_H__

#include "winsock2.h"
#include "ws2tcpip.h"

#include <thread>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
```

(cpp includes only the header)

```
//CSocket.cpp
#include "CSocket.h"
```

produces the following error messages in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\ratio

```
ratio(122): error C2065: 'INTMAX_MAX': undeclared identifier
ratio(133): See reference to the instance of the just compiled class-template "std::ratio<_Nx,_Dx>".
ratio(124): error C2065: 'INTMAX_MAX': undeclared identifier
ratio(44): error C2065: 'INTMAX_MAX': undeclared identifier
ratio(217): See reference to the instance of the just compiled class-template "std::_Safe_mult<0x01,0x01>".
ratio(36): error C2338: integer arithmetic overflow
ratio(44): See reference to the instance of the just compiled class-template "std::_Safe_multX<0x01,0x01,false>".
ratio(44): error C2039: 'value': Is not an element of 'std::_Safe_multX<0x01,0x01,false>'
ratio(44): error C2065: 'value': undeclared identifier
ratio(44): error C2057: Expected constant expression
ratio(44): error C2039: 'value': Is not an element of 'std::_Safe_multX<0x01,0x0989680,false>'
ratio(219): error C2975: "_Nx": invalid template argument for "std::ratio", expected compile-time constant expression.
ratio(116): See declaration of '_Nx'
ratio(219): error C2975: "_Dx": invalid template argument for "std::ratio", expected compile-time constant expression.
ratio(117): See declaration of '_Dx'
CSocket.cpp
```

Including std::thread in the .cpp and not in the header solves all errors but I don't know why it doesn't work in the header.

```
//CSocket.cpp
#include "CSocket.h"
#include <thread>
```

---

The only library I am using is jemalloc.
Might the error come from including jemalloc.h before mutex not from thread itself?

Comment: Can you translate those messages into English?

Comment: "Including std::thread in the .cpp and not in the header solves all errors" - are you including it before including `"CSocket.h"` in that case?

Comment: No, and yeah I both tried to include thread after and before all the other includes in CSocket.h ;)
I added a litte bit of information about my attempts on googling the problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem.  Please provide a minimal source file that exhibits the problem.  (I tried with your first "source file," but that compiles successfully.)

Comment: Side note: `__SERVER_CSOCKET_H__` is a reserved identifier.

Comment: Please come back when you've finished debugging, not during it.

Comment: Seems like the error came from doing #include "jemalloc\jemalloc.h" before #include <mutex>. I will try to fully implement everything and if it still works I'll close the question. Thank you all for the quick replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to `#include <mutex>` before `#include "jemalloc.h"` and not afterwards.
Works fine now, strange errors though.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same error, but the order of the includes is not useful for me. I think this has something to do with other includes that also use chrono and thread, so you can checkout that.

Are you using Visual Studio? Seems like more people is getting the same error: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800726/compiler-error

Comment: Yes, I am using Visual Studio (tested it with 2013 Professional with Update 3 & 4 and with Community 2013).

Comment: I am using that version too. Maybe we should post it in the Microsoft support page!

Comment: Check the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24798033/is-it-possible-to-use-stdchronoduration-with-rep-type-as-double-i-get-compi?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, that might well be the cause of our problem I guess.

Comment: Thank you for leaving this. Sometimes environment, compiler, etc is an important detail. I really appreciate it. +1 for you brother.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same errors with VS2013 update 3. The problem seems to be the fact that `INTMAX_MAX` is not defined, but it is used in ratio.h.

My solution is to add

```
#define INTMAX_MAX   INT64_MAX
```

before `#include <ratio>` in your file (if you do not have the line, you may add it).

The line to be included can be found in `stdint.h` - in your case, the right side can be different.

PS Another solution is to `#include <stdint.h>` and to define  `__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS`. In this case, you may get some warnings about duplicate macros.

Answer (score 1):

it occurs to the project when i use the CxImage as third party library and with threadpool in C++11. Separately they are all okay, while merged in the same project, that errors occur.

the [solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3a3dc941-af59-4788-b75e-74e585a25f3e/compile-issue-vs2015-undeclared-its-in-stdinth-intmaxmax?forum=vcgeneral) is add the precompile option of _STDC_LIMIT_MACROS to 
Property Pages -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions of the Project.

PS: my environment is : MFC/VS2015 && windows7 64bit

may it be helpful to somebody :)